# How to select a record and update it, with a single queryset in Django?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

How do I run an `update` and `select` statements on the same `queryset` rather than having to do two queries: 
- one to select the object
- and one to update the object

The equivalent in SQL would be something like:

```
update my_table set field_1 = 'some value' where pk_field = some_value
```

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Use the queryset [object `update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-update):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1='some value')
```

Comment: Just a fair warning... if you use the `update` method like this then any signals attached to that model or other "code stuff" won't run against the objects.  Just a pointer from someone who got burned :)

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer dude thanks for that valuable info. Then should we use the older way of updating it? (ie) get and save?

Comment: @learning well dude, it all depends on your scenario.  The `update` method is great for mass updates, but it should set off a warning in your head when you use it that you need to review any signals attached to that object that might also need to be manually fired

Comment: Is it possible to access the current model instance in the update function? like `MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1=self.data)`

Comment: @DipakChandranP You should ask a new question rather than putting comments on a six-year-old one. But F() expressions are probably want you want.

Comment: Why this method is not updating Image Field?? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040591/django-imagefield-is-not-updating-when-update-method-is-used)

Comment: it is worth noting that, `filter()` may return multiple queries if a unique key is not used to filter. In this case, the `update()` will do a bulk update by updating all queries returned. So, I think in some point, it is better to use the `get()` then `save()` if we want to be sure that only a single unique query is updated.

Comment: @EyongKevinEnowanyo If you have a primary key or otherwise know that it will return only 1 record, the `update()` is much faster since it only has to do 1 remote query instead of 2.

Comment: @DMactheDestroyer 9 years later, I finally understand your comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71688507/417899

Comment: How to `.update` only the _first_ record in the query?

Comment: `.update()` doesn't works with `.get()`

Answer (score 131):

Django database objects use the same save() method for creating and changing objects.

```
obj = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
obj.name = "some_new_value"
obj.save()
```

> **How Django knows to UPDATE vs. INSERT**
>   If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to True (i.e., a value
>   other than None or the empty string), Django executes an UPDATE. If
>   the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t
>   update anything, Django executes an INSERT.

Ref.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 32):

This answer compares the above two approaches.
If you want to update many objects in a single line, go for:

```
# Approach 1
MyModel.objects.filter(field1='Computer').update(field2='cool')
```

Otherwise you would have to iterate over the query set and update individual objects:

```
#Approach 2    
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(field1='Computer')
for obj in objects:
    obj.field2 = 'cool'
    obj.save()
```

1. Approach 1 is faster because, it makes only one database query, compared to approach 2 which makes 'n+1' database queries. (For n items in the query set)
2. Fist approach makes one db query ie UPDATE, the second one makes two: SELECT and then UPDATE.
3. The tradeoff is that, suppose you have any triggers, like updating `updated_on` or any such related fields, it will not be triggered on direct update ie approach 1.
4. Approach 1 is used on a queryset, so it is possible to update multiple objects at once, not in the case of approach 2.

Comment: Regarding 1. - I think the query result gets cached on first call to query, hence there is actually still just a one call to DB.

Comment: For 3 tradeoff.  Is there anyway we can fix it?

Answer (score 30):

**1st method**

```
MyTable.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1='some value')
```

**2nd Method**

```
q = MyModel.objects.get(pk=some_value)
q.field1 = 'some value'
q.save()
```

**3rd method**

By using `get_object_or_404`

```
q = get_object_or_404(MyModel,pk=some_value)
q.field1 = 'some value'
q.save()
```

**4th Method**

if you required if `pk=some_value` exist then `update` it other wise `create` new one by using `update_or_create`.

```
MyModel.objects.update_or_create(pk=some_value,defaults={'field1':'some value'})
```

Comment: I want to use method #2 but with `q["field1"] = 'some value'`... however, I get the error "TypeError: 'User' object does not support item assignment" -- is there another way to do this? I have the field name in a variable

Answer (score 6):

If you need to set the new value based on the old field value that is do something like:

```
update my_table set field_1 = field_1 + 1 where pk_field = some_value
```

use [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(field1=F('field1') + 1)
```

This will execute update atomically that is using one update request to the database without reading it first.

Answer (score 2):

**only in a case in `serializer` things, you can update in very simple way!**

```
my_model_serializer = MyModelSerializer(
    instance=my_model, data=validated_data)
if my_model_serializer.is_valid():

    my_model_serializer.save()
```

**only in a case in `form` things!**

```
instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: I think serializers are from Djanog Rest Framework and not Django proper.

Comment: Yeah, however `Django form` is from Django Proper.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer works great, but it comes with some unwanted side effect.

For example, you are using imageField, the update() will work and update others data, but not update your imageField data

```
class ProfileSetting(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True)

    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="profile/logo/")
```

```
update_data = {
  "first_name": "john",
  "logo": request.FILES['logo'] # logo will not be properly update
}

ProfileSetting.objects.filter(pk=some_value).update(**update_data)
```

Here is some example with good explanation [Django ImageField is not updating when update() method is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040591/django-imagefield-is-not-updating-when-update-method-is-used)

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned answer works great, but it happens with some unwanted side effect, so to avoid such errors writes your db code inside exception blocks.

```
    try:
        obj = <Your_Model_Name>.objects.get(PK=<pk_id>)
        obj.name = req.POST.get("name")
        obj.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```