# Can you save a new object over an existing object?

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following `Listing` model.  I retrieve a listing and store that in `old_listing`, and set up a new one and store that in `new_listing`.  Now is there some way to save `new_listing` into `old_listing`, basically overriding all fields except the auto-incrementing `id` field?

```
class Listing(models.Model):
   street = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

---

```
old_listing = Listing.objects.get(id=1) # Assuming this record already exists
new_listing = Listing(street='123 Main Street')

old_listing.save(new_listing) # This obviously doesn't work
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because the actual `Listing` model has a lot of fields, and many fields require custom cleaning logic.  This way I can avoid having to copy and paste many of the logic.

Comment: But that appears to be the opposite of what you've described in the question. You say you want to override all the fields of the *old* object with the new one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes.  Before I add a listing, I first check if an older version of the same listing exists.  If it does exist, then I need to update the old listing with the newer listing.  This is where I can choose between several options, like the option I mentioned in my question, or the answers listed on a question like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712682/django-update-object.  It would seem my method would be the easiest for my situation, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_listing.id = old_listing.id
new_listing.save()
```

This should work.