# Django ImageField is not updating when update() method is used

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I am updating some of fields in model from views.py file. All other fields are updated properly when I use

```
Profile.objects.filter(id=user_profile.id).update(
        bio=bio,
        city=city,
        date_of_birth=dob,
        profile_pic=profile_pic,
        gender=gender
    )
```

only, `profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True)` is not updated, Weird thing is when I check my `Profile` model from admins.py it shows me the file name which I uploaded, But my file is not shown in my `/media` directory(where I upload my all Images)

views.py

```
def edit_submit(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_pic = request.POST.get('profile_pic')
    bio = request.POST.get('bio')
    city = request.POST.get('city')
    dob = request.POST.get('dob')
    gender = request.POST.get('gender')
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    Profile.objects.filter(id=user_profile.id).update(
        bio=bio,
        city=city,
        date_of_birth=dob,
        profile_pic=profile_pic,
        gender=gender
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[user_profile.id]))
```

This is how I manage my media files in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I think only text is stored in ImageField and Image is not uploded to `/media` directory
Note: I am using `<input type="file" name="profile_pic" class="change_user_img">` for getting image from template

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `QuerySet.update()` method doesn't call `save()` on the model, and so the usual mechanism that places the image into storage is not executed. In addition, you must retrieve the uploaded image from `request.FILES` not `request.POST`.

Rather than using `update()`, if you set the attributes on the model instance and then call `save()`, the image should get saved to the correct place on disk. For example:

```
profile_pic = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')  # Use request.FILES

bio = request.POST.get('bio')
city = request.POST.get('city')
dob = request.POST.get('dob')
gender = request.POST.get('gender')

user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
user_profile.bio = bio
user_profile.city = city
user_profile.date_of_birth = dob
user_profile.profile_pic = profile_pic
user_profile.gender = gender
user_profile.save()
```

You must also ensure that the form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set.

Comment: code same but giving error of **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'.**  Can you look at my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042995/django-save-image-without-using-django-forms). my model doesn't have a save method, guess it will be inherited from models.Model. Do we need a QuerySet object for using the save method?

Comment: Hey, I change from .update() to .save() but the problem is still the same. I can see in admin panel that the `ImageField` has been changed but the photo isnt saving in the directory

Answer (score 0):

Specify `upload_to` on `profile_pic = ...`:  [Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield).

Comment: By default I configured my settings.py to store all images in `/media` dirictory....

Comment: How do you have MEDIA_ROOT defined?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: Updated media root in question...@Dan Swain

Comment: Is BASE_DIR defined something like the following?  
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

Comment: And do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" on your <form> tag?