# Django - instances

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, instance, mixing

How can i use in my views instances from other class?

For example in my views i have:

MODELS

```
class Projekt(models.Model):
    nazwa_projektu = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    opis_projektu = models.TextField()
    wybor_projekt = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=wybor_t_f, default="FALSZ")
```

VIEWS

```
def ProjektViewOptions(request, pk):
    profil = Profil.objects.get(user=request.user)
    projekt = Projekt.objects.get(id=pk)
    srodek = projekt.srodek_set.all

    form = OptionsForm(request.POST or None)
    template_name = 'viewOptionsProjekt.html'

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            pro.wybor_projekt = 'PRAWDA'
            pro.save()
            opcje = form.save(commit=False)
            opcje.wlasciciel = profil
            opcje.projekt = projekt
            opcje.save()
            opcje.wybor = 'PRAWDA'
            form.save()
```

I want to do that, if i create a new Project this project have a options "FALSZ" when I "POST"   this options will turn into the "PRAWDA"

I tried do :

```
opcje.projekt.wybor_projekt = "PRAWDA"
```

But this unfortunately dont work.

I dont want full solution. I need a little direction. ;)

Comment: have you imported the model in your views file? like ```from .models import Projekt``` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712682/how-to-select-a-record-and-update-it-with-a-single-queryset-in-django

Comment: `opcje.projekt.wybor_projekt = "PRAWDA"` -- in this line, you need to save `projekt` to apply the changes

Comment: I do it, thanks osint_alex, direction with update was good direction. Thanks